# Matching partial Attribute values with selector

Tags: javascript

Trying to get matches of attributes with wildcards to find out how many elements of a type are on the page

I think I should be able to use queryselectorAll on a partial attribute value as shown below, but no elements found :(

```
<div class="ag-right-align-cell" data-test="unitPrice&amp;^%^&amp;category=FRED&amp;^%^&amp;displayName=FREDS INFO;field=unitPrice&amp;^%^&amp;^%^&amp;">$999.99</div>

<div class="ag-right-align-cell" data-test="unitPrice&amp;^%^&amp;category=GEORGE&amp;^%^&amp;displayName=GEORGES INFO;field=unitPrice&amp;^%^&amp;^%^&amp;">$999.99</div>
```

```js
var el=document.querySelectorAll('[data-test|=unitprice]');
console.log(el.length);  // = 0
```

el.length shows 0 elements found.

What is the correct javascript for a match for selecting datatest=unitprice* ?

Comment: `unitprice` != `unitPrice`. Also, you probably need `^=` intead of `|=`.

Comment: Use `^=` to check if an attribute starts with some value, or `*=` to check if an attribute has the value somewhere in it (and fix the typo)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen is completely right. You need to fix the case on "unitPrice" and use ^= instead of |=

Comment: Thanks all, I did try the other answers, but could pull enough info from them. I used 

```js
var el=document.querySelectorAll('[data-test^="unitPrice"]');
```